# What's the Bitwise Tunnnlier equivalent for Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, ssh

I used Tunnlier in windows and it was perfect. After migrating to Linux I, surprisingly,  can't find anything that does the following:

- manage my SSH connections
- use Terminal and SFTP browser
- save my connections as profiles to load later

I found PuTTY and gSTM, but they really don't do what I mentioned above.

What do you recommend?

---

*moved here from [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/181649/whats-the-bitwise-tunnnlier-equivalent-for-linux)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple: PAC Manager. Download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/ or, **even better**, add the GetDeb page to repositories and then update and apt-get install pac

Comment: i looked at it's shots. it seems to be great!! i will try it... +1 for intro

Comment: i tested it. it was great! i'm surprised no one next to me knew about it!

Answer (score 3):

Afaik there is no program that can do this for you for Linux. You can do this on Linux, but there isn't a pretty GUI for doing it.
Password-less login can be done by using ssh-keys (You might still want a password for you ssh-key, but you only have to enter it once!) Have a [look here](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/).

By configuring the ssh client on a host basis you can have individual settings for different hosts. Have a look at the file in /home/user/.ssh/config (it might not be there, but just create it.) Mine looks something like this:

```
CheckHostIP yes
ConnectionAttempts 3
ServerAliveInterval 10

Host router
        HostName 10.0.0.1
        User root

Host test
        HostName test.example.org
        User test32
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
        ForwardX11 yes
        Compression yes
        CompressionLevel 6

Host lucretia
        User lasse
        HostName 8.8.8.8

Host home
        User coax
        HostName 8.8.8.9

Host lovelace
        User lasse
        HostName 8.8.8.10

Host mailserver
        User lasse
        HostName 8.8.8.11
        ForwardX11 yes
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Everything before the first `Host` deceleration is common to all connections. For more options look at the man-page for `ssh_config`.

When you have set up the config file then you can use `ssh home` instead of `ssh 8.8.8.9 -l coax` These options also applies to nautilus for ssh:// browsing.

You then have two options for quick launching a ssh terminal session, one is to create a gnome-terminal session for each and create launchers that runs `gnome-terminal --profile='profile-name'`.
The other option is to install [sshmenu](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/), imho not a super app, but it does a good job of supplying quick access to remote terminals.

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus (`Applications -> Accessories -> File Browser`) provides support to connect to ssh servers and browse files over sftp and to save the connections as profiles (Saved data includes server name, share name, username, password).

To open sftp, go to `Places -> Connect to Server...` and choose "SSH" or FTP as the type and enter the rest of the details - see [this guide](http://blogote.com/2010/ubuntu/how-to-connect-to-ftp-or-sftp-server-in-ubuntu.html) for detailed steps. By giving a bookmark name, this connection profile will be stored for easy access in the left-hand side pane (`View -> Side Pane`).

Only thing I don't know a way to do within nautilus is "Open a terminal", for which u can use Putty, etc. Agree it is not yet as integrated as the option you mention, but it may be possible to find a way to "Open a Terminal" while on an sftp location to open an ssh connection in a terminal and jump to the directory.

Comment: the main problem is the SSH. i want an application that i just asked for a profile and it connect and open a terminal for me. (i don't being asked for a password or IP each time)

Comment: you can bookmark the connections you make using "connect to a server" and if and when you need the command line you can use the terminal "ssh user@domain.com"

Comment: @takpar: to avoid being prompted for a password, use ssh key authentication instead (see the link in Source Lab's answer). Even if you use a password for the key (which is better security), you'll only be prompted once per session.

Answer (score 2):

Try HotSSH (found in the repositories). It manages the ssh connections very nicely, including connection sharing. I don't think it handles SFTP, though as someone else has noted, you can do that through Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

You manage the different connections in different programs that use them.
Here's what you do:

- add the SSH as a mount using nautilus (Locations -> Connect to server) and mark 'add bookmark'

  - put your public key in the .ssh directory on the server. It's not smart to keep reconnecting with your real password all the time. You should be using a password less setup, if you want to prevent any man in the middle attacks.
  - gnome-do automatically indexes known ssh hosts, so you can connect quickly using that. There is also an ssh applet, and you can offcourse just add a few aliases to your bash.